# Please help, I'm new, and my 'if' is working fine, but my 'else' is not working at all

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print("Welcome to Last call!\n" "The game where you make last minute decisions before the bar closes.\n" "Be careful, some decisions are better than others.")

print("Oh no! You look at your phone and see it's 30 minutes until closing time!\n" "You see your fried Harry standing by the bathroom.\n" "You also see a beautiful woman sitting alone at the bar.")

person = input("Who do you talk to? Harry or Stephanie?\n")


if person == "stephanie" or "Stephanie":
    print("Things are going well with Stephanie.\n" "The bartender shouts 'Last call for alcohol!'\n" "Stephanie asks if you will buy her a drink.")
    drink = input("Do you buy Stephanie a beer or Appletini?\n")
    
    if drink == "Appletini" or "appletini":
        print("Things are going really well and you're definitely into each other.")
        liquid_courage = input("Stephanie goes to the restroom to freshen up.\n" "Harry comes by and offers you the rest of his Jack & Coke.\n" "Do you drink the liquid courage?\n" "Yes or No?\n")
        if liquid_courage == "No" or "no":
            print("Stephanie comes back and sits down.\n" "She looks into your eyes and asks for a kiss.\n" "Then she asks if you want to go to her place.\n" "YOU WIN!")
        else:
            print("You drink the liquid courage.\n" "Stephanie comes back and sits down.\n" "She looks into your eyes and asks for a kiss.\n" "You lean in... ...and PUKE all over her face & dress.\n" "She screams and storms off.\n" "GAME OVER.")
    else:
        print("Stephanie loses interest in you because 'Beer has too many carbs'.\n" "She calls an Uber and leaves.\n" "You buy booze on the way home and drown your sorrows into a bottle of whiskey at home.\n" "GAME OVER.")
else:
    print("Harry talks to you about comic books for 35 minutes.\n" "The bar closes, and you leave alone to Filibertos' to drown your sorrows in Super Nachos.\n" "GAME OVER.")
```

Comment: `person == "stephanie" or "Stephanie"` is always `True` because of how `or` and operator precedence work.  If your `if` is always `True` the `else` will never happen. 
 Do `person.lower() == "stephanie"` instead.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and explaining what the problem is?

Comment: If you want to accept only a limited set of options, use `if person in ["stephanie", "Stephanie"]:`